# How do I report an unauthorized copy app uploaded to App Store?

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

I am a contributor to TableTool, a modest app for editing CSV files. Somebody took our source code, copied it and is charging money for the identical app, Quick CSV.

[image]

I don't mind this, our project is Open Source and copying our code is allowed, even for commercial purposes. Even though this developer, Erik Wegener is just benefiting from someone else’s (communities’) work.

The logo used is deceptively similar to ours which is intended to imply an official association. Also, they are using our product's name as a search term which is intended to imply an association.

This is improper use of our product's icon and name. How do I make an official complaint to Apple?

Comment: Can you confirm you have a legal agreement with Apple as part of their developer program? If so - you have a dedicated team to work with. if not, the answer will be different. Would you please edit your post to explain if you are part of Apple Development program or not? I've edited the tags to make it look like you are part of that program - if not, you'll need to change the tag to be apple or App Store perhaps.

Comment: @bmike From the screenshot it appears that the original app is published on the Mac App Store. Doesn't that imply developer program association with Apple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try getting in touch with Apple via the [App Store Content Dispute](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstorenotices/) page.

> If you believe that an application or Search Ad available in the App Store violates your intellectual property rights, you can use this form to submit a claim to the App Store Legal Team.

If you suspect copyright infringements, you can use the info provided in the [Legal Claims of Copyright Infringement](https://www.apple.com/legal/contact/copyrightInfringementthankyou.html) page.

**Note**: Please don’t treat this as professional legal advice of any sort. Just a couple of pointers to get you started towards potential resolution.

Comment: I would say you will have far greater success having your lawyer reach out to Apple for discovery in a civil suit. Apple has to be hesitant to arbitrate between developers. What if you are the bad guy that wants to take down another legit developer and file a claim that looks to Apple like it’s legit? The only case where going to Apple directly will work is when the other party concedes once they get called on it.